# Why was the maven dependency excluded?

Tags: java, maven

After executing `mvn dependency:tree`, I got the following output:

```
[INFO] stpr:stpr:war:1.0
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:
1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.resource:jboss-connector-api_1.5_spec:jar:1.0.
0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:pro
vided
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.el:jboss-el-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provi
ded
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:ja
r:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc:jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec:jar:1.0.
0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.deploy:jboss-jad-api_1.2_spec:jar:1
.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message:jboss-jaspi-api_1.0_spec
:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.registry:jboss-jaxr-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.0
.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:pro
vided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp:jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.F
inal:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.F
inal:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar
:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Fin
al:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc:jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Fi
nal:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap:jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec:jar:1.0.0.Fin
al:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws:jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Fina
l:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-b05:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Fin
al:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.1.0.GA:provided
[INFO] |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2-b03:compile
```

My question is why `javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2-b03:compile` were excluded? I didn't specify any exclusion explicitly. What's wrong?

The `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>gr</groupId>
  <artifactId>ar</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>nm</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2-b03</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
       <!-- profiles here -->
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output does not show any exclusion for the dependency. In fact, if the dependency were excluded, it would not have been shown in the dependency tree. By looking at the tree, the dependency is shown in the last line:

```
[INFO] \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2-b03:compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to update your maven project to reload the dependencies.